# C++: o que significa SIGSEGV

Tags: c++

Estou fazendo uma classe numérica dinâmica, porém quando vou testar, recebo a mensagem **"Program recived signal SIGSEGV"**. Sei que isso é um erro com ponteiros, mas por que ele ocorre e como eu corrijo?

```
typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef unsigned short ushort;
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned long ulong;

class Num
{
private:
    vector<uchar> x;
    ushort len;
    ...
public:
    ...
    Num(vector<uchar> other)
    {
        if(other.size() > 8) other.resize(8);

        while(other[other.size() - 1] == 0)
            other.pop_back();

        x = other;
        len = x.size();
    }
    ...
    friend Num operator+(Num l, const Num& rhs)
    {
        Num r = rhs;
        vector<uchar> res (l.x);
        vector<uchar> mod (1, 0);

        while(r.x.size() < res.size()) r.x.push_back(0);
        while(r.x.size() > res.size()) res.push_back(0);

        for(uchar i = 0; i < res.size(); i++)
        {
            mod.push_back((ushort)res[i] + (ushort)r.x[i] > 0xff);
            res[i] += r.x[i];
        }
        if(mod.size() > 0) return (Num(res) + Num(mod));
        return Num(res);
    }
    ...
};
```

Comment: _segmentation fault_?

Comment: @LINQ A mensagem que recebo é _"Program Recived signal SIGSEGV   Stack trace is available in 'Call Stack' tab"_

Comment: Mas é um *segmentation fault* como o LINQ indicou. Significa que acedeu a um endereço de memoria invalido.

Comment: [Essa imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szklj.png) explica bem o problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você recebe um `SIGSEGV`, que é o sinal `11`, quando seu programa referencia uma área de memória inválida. Isso implica no interrompimento inesperado da sua aplicação, como já notado.

Se você passar um vetor só com valores `0` para o construtor `Num` você pode receber um `SIGSEGV` por que o código acaba acessando um índice negativo e talvez até retirar um valor do vetor `other` já quando vazio:

```
    while(other[other.size() - 1] == 0)
        other.pop_back();
```

Sugiro alterar para:

```
    while(!other.empty() && other[other.size() - 1] == 0)
        other.pop_back();
```

Comment: O problema é esse mesmo, obrigado. Porém, tive que trocar `if (mod.size() > 0)` em `operator+` para `Num nmod = mod;    if(nmod.len > 0)`

Comment: Você sabe algum lugar onde eu possa ler sobre o assunto?

Comment: Não recomendo utilizar a variável `len` a não ser que realmente seja realmente necessário ter o tamanho do vetor duplicado no objeto. Acredito que você poderia resolver esse problema do `if (mod.len > 0)` com uma variável local.

Sobre o "assunto" você quer dizer `SIGSEGV`?

Comment: Sobre o "assunto", sim. Criei `len` porque quando uso `const Num`, não consigo ter acesso a `x.size()`

Comment: Para poder ter acesso ao tamanho do vetor em uma variável `const` basta adicionar um método do tipo `const`, declarado e implementado como `std::size_t size() const { return x.size(); }`. Sobre o `SIGSEGV` sugiro o Wikipedia em inglês: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault